# PDO query not returning expected result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a forum for my game. Currently I'm working on the edit function. What I'm trying to figure out how I could check that the logged in account owns the player that posted the message. **You post with your player, not account. You can have several players.** An user can have several "players" assigned to them. If they don't own the player that posted the message I want to return false, but if they do, true.

```
# table accounts
id | username | password

# table posts
id | posterid (this is the player id) | message

# table players
id | account_id | name
```

This is how far I have come. But this returns false no matter what. There is a post with ID 666 and the player that posted it is owned by account 34767. So it should work.

```
function can_we_edit_post($pid) {

global $db;

// Let's see if they have permission to edit
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM players pl a JOIN posts p ON p.id = $pid WHERE pl.account_id = 34767");
$stmt->execute(array(34767));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

// Check if we got any rows
if ($row) {
    return true;
} else {
   return false;
}

}

if (can_we_edit_post(666)) {
   echo "You may edit this post.";
} else {
  echo "You do not own this post.";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your query be `pl.account_id = ?`?

Comment: yes my bad! but still dont work, it always returns false hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an errant `a` after `pl`, so your query is probably failing

```
SELECT * FROM players pl a JOIN posts p ON p.id = $pid WHERE pl.account_id = 34767
                         ^
```

try something like this (using placeholders to prevent SQL injection) -

```
// Let's see if they have permission to edit
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM players pl JOIN posts p ON p.id = ? WHERE pl.account_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($pid, 34767));
$row = $stmt->rowCount();
```

take a look at this sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e282a1/2 - without the `a` the query returns a result, with the `a` the query fails with an error.

**EDIT**
It is probably returning `true` for every player, because you hardcoded the `pl.account_id` -

```
WHERE pl.account_id = 34767
```

and you are not verifying if the `posterid` matches the `pl.id` for the specific `post.id` which you can do by adding - `AND p.posterid = pl.id` to your `JOIN`

```
function can_we_edit_post($pid,$aid) {

global $db;

// Let's see if they have permission to edit
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM players pl JOIN posts p ON p.id = ? AND p.posterid = pl.id WHERE pl.account_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($pid, $aid));

// Check if we got any rows
if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
    return true;
} else {
   return false;
}

}


if (can_we_edit_post(666,34767)) { // change 34767 to each player account_id ie. $player->account_id
   echo "You may edit this post.";
} else {
  echo "You do not own this post.";
}
```

Comment: thanks how could i miss that. now I only need to figure out why it returns true even if account dont own that player

Comment: It is probably returning `true` because you hardcoded in the `pl.account_id`. I will add an edit with a way to fix.

Comment: well no matter what posterid is as long as the account exist anyone can edit the post hmm

Comment: Try adding `AND p.posterid = pl.account_id` in your `JOIN` - `SELECT * FROM players pl JOIN posts p ON p.id = ? AND p.posterid = pl.account_id WHERE pl.account_id = ?`. This way it will only join if the posterid matches the account_id for the specific post id. I have added this to my **EDIT** code example.

Comment: posterid is the player id not account_id, you post with your player not your account, a user can have several players

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. Then do `AND p.posterid = pl.id`. I have corrected it in the above edit.

Comment: @Kaka: this problem would have been clear if you set up some error handling around your calls. With databases, you should make _every_ call as if you are expecting it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You are using PDO wrong. You should do it like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM players pl a JOIN posts p ON p.id = :pid WHERE pl.account_id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $pid, ':id' => 34767));
return (($stmt->rowCount() > 0)? true : false);
```

PDO and execute is genius because you just supply keys you want to replace with values, and it will escape and make it harmless for you.

If the rest of the query is correct, this code should work. `rowCount` returns the number of rows returned by the query. If you just want to see if it returns anything, you can use this instead of using `fetch`.

Comment: You left it open to SQL injection still ;)

Comment: thanks! i just recently started using pdo instead of mysql and mysqli for many years

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau: What? I did? I thought prepare and execute was meant to fix this for me? I know this is offtopic, but you mind explaining further?

Comment: @Kaka: Then try to run your query in phpmyadmin or something to check that it is correct. This script should fix it. If there's something wrong with your query, you should ask that in a separate question.

Comment: @OptimusCrime your example is still open to SQL injection due to using `p.id = $pid` in the query - `SELECT * FROM players pl JOIN posts p ON p.id = $pid WHERE pl.account_id = :id`. Edit to `SELECT * FROM players pl JOIN posts p ON p.id = :pid WHERE pl.account_id = :id` & `$stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $pid,':id' => 34767));`

Comment: @Sean Ahh, I overlooked that variable. Fixed in my answer. Thank you.